# CSV file has an error or it's not an SYLYK File when adding ID header

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, npm, wps

So I created a node.js script to convert the object of an array to CSV format, then I used [objects-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv) from NPM libraries. First, is want to iterate the array by adding an ID. The script was successfully created the CSV file. but when I open it to the WPS and Microsoft Office, there was a warning that either a file has an error or it's not an SYLYK File. please see the code below.

```js
const ObjectsToCsv = require("objects-to-csv");

// Sample data - two columns, three rows:
const data = [
  { code: "CA", name: "California" },
  { code: "TX", name: "Texas" },
  { code: "NY", name: "New York" },
];

// If you use "await", code must be inside an asynchronous function:
(async () => {
  const iterateWithID = data.map((x, i) => {
    return {
      ID: i + 1,
      code: x.code,
      name: x.name,
    };
  });

  const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(iterateWithID);

  // Save to file:
  await csv.toDisk("./output.csv");

  // Return the CSV file as string:
  console.log(await csv.toString());
})();
```

here is the screenshot of the warning when I open it to the WPS
[image]

I tried to remove the iteration of the array, and I didn't encounter any problem when opening the CSV file.
What I really want to fix this warning when I open the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the first letters `ID` of a text file, Excel incorrectly assumes you are trying to open an SYLK file. I updated your code to have `Id` instead of `ID`.

```js
const ObjectsToCsv = require("objects-to-csv");

// Sample data - two columns, three rows:
const data = [
  { code: "CA", name: "California" },
  { code: "TX", name: "Texas" },
  { code: "NY", name: "New York" },
];

// If you use "await", code must be inside an asynchronous function:
(async () => {
  const iterateWithID = data.map((x, i) => {
    return {
      Id: i + 1,
      code: x.code,
      name: x.name,
    };
  });

  const csv = new ObjectsToCsv(iterateWithID);

  // Save to file:
  await csv.toDisk("./output.csv");

  // Return the CSV file as string:
  console.log(await csv.toString());
})();
```